# How do I solve for the real and complex parts of an equation simultaneously?

Tags: equation-solving, complex

If I were to have an equation, say something similar to...

```
(1-Sqrt[x - I y])/(1+Sqrt[x - I y]) = A + I B
```

Where I = Sqrt[-1], is there a way for Mathematica to give me A = ... and B = ..., i.e. both real and imaginary parts of the equation simultaneously?

Comment: Hi ! You are not using the correct syntax - are you sure you know your way around Mathematica ?

Comment: Hi, I'm actually brand new to Mathematica.  That equation is just an example I was using to describe my problem, not the one I need to solve (the real one is fairly long).  Is there a better way I should be asking my question?

Comment: In that case - I don't think there is :) You can start by looking at `Reduce`, `Solve` and `ComplexExpand`.

Comment: Ok great, thank you!  So for example, if I wanted to use the ComplexExpand command on the above expression, it would look something like this...

ComplexExpand[(1-Sqrt[x - I y])/(1+Sqrt[x - I y]) = A + Ib,{A}] 

for the real part?

Comment: Also, thank you Sjoerd for editing it to the correct format

Comment: You shouldn't guess how to use a function, but look it up in the built-in  documentation. Your suggested use of ComplexExpand is simply wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ComplexExpand[
  Solve[
    {
      Re[(1 - Sqrt[x - I y])/(1 + Sqrt[x - I y])] == A, 
      Im[(1 - Sqrt[x - I y])/(1 + Sqrt[x - I y])] == B
    }, 
    {A, B}
  ],
  TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}
]

(* {{A -> 1/((1 + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/4)*Cos[(1/2)*ArcTan[x, -y]])^2 + 
              Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]*Sin[(1/2)*ArcTan[x, -y]]^2) - 
         (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]*Cos[(1/2)*ArcTan[x, -y]]^2)/
           ((1 + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/4)*Cos[(1/2)*ArcTan[x, -y]])^2 + 
              Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]*Sin[(1/2)*ArcTan[x, -y]]^2) - 
         (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]*Sin[(1/2)*ArcTan[x, -y]]^2)/
           ((1 + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/4)*Cos[(1/2)*ArcTan[x, -y]])^2 + 
              Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]*Sin[(1/2)*ArcTan[x, -y]]^2), 
     B -> -((2*(x^2 + y^2)^(1/4)*Sin[(1/2)*ArcTan[x, -y]])/
            ((1 + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/4)*Cos[(1/2)*ArcTan[x, -y]])^2 + 
               Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]*Sin[(1/2)*ArcTan[x, -y]]^2))}} *)
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much!  So just so I'm clear, by doing this, it is solving the equation one time only for the real part, A, and then solving it again for the imaginary part, B?

Comment: @tair something like that, but don't forget that the real and imaginary parts may be totally different and are completely independent, so saying that you use the same equation twice is not completely true.